# get name and value from specific post

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I got a checkbox and i want to pass all the values into a function in order to update a table.

The checkbox has 60 options and i generate them with a foreach() from mysql.

**// html form**

```
<div class="form-group">
<?  $i = 0; 
    foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value) {
        if ($value =='on') { ?>
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><?= $title ?></label>
            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0px;">
                <div class="make-switch switch-small" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
                    <input id="specs_value" name="<?= $title ?>" type="checkbox" value="on" checked/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? } else { ?>
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><?= $title ?></label>
            <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0px;">
                <div class="make-switch switch-small" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
                    <input id="specs_value" name="<?= $title ?>" type="checkbox" value="off"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?} $i++;
            if($i % 4 == 0) { ?> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
        <?} }?>
```

**// function**

```
foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value) {

    $value = $_REQUEST[$title];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `specifics` SET $title = '$value' WHERE `car_id`= $id");
}
```

**QUESTION:** How can i get the title and the value from `$_POST` and use it in the function and the update query ?

The `$_POST` gets only the values that are 'on'. Not the 'off'. I could either get them all or just get the title from value with the value in order to use it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop verify with isset if `$_POST['title']` exist, that means checkbox is on:

```
foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value) {

    $valueToInsert = ( isset($_POST[$title]) ) ? $value : null;

    if( $valueToInsert ) {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `specifics` SET $title = '{$valueToInsert}' WHERE `car_id`= $id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce. The table is not been updated after i change an option to `on`. No errors

Comment: `$valueToInsert` returns only the value but we need the current title to be uset in the query

Comment: The current title is `title` because you're in the loop at the moment of verification `if( $valueToInsert )`

Comment: `foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value)` ->>> title is the key

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is another error on the checkbox option generator that i'll have to check, that why it's not updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not on topic but not exactly off topic... You could simplify your code to make it more manageable and easier to read.

```
<? foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value): ?>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><?= $title ?></label>
        <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0px;">
            <div class="make-switch switch-small" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
                <input id="specs_value" name="<?= $title ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?= $value?>"<?= $value=='on' ? 'checked' : ''?>/>
           </div>
        </div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

This will remove the need for the if statement and the block of repeated code.

Comment: Thank you for that. I saw it on another question before and i was about to edit my code on this after i solve the update function